# 1D scalar wave equation with complex wave speed

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I am interested in solutions $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ of the standard 1D wave equation
$$
c^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f(x,t) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} f(x,t)
$$
except with $c$ complex.

I'm a bit surprised that I don't find any useful references for this. Presumably, the [d'Alembert's Solution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsSolution.html) still works if we use holomorphic functions $y_0,v_0$ (?)
$$f(x,t)=y_0(x+ct)+y_0(x-ct)$$

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: When I try it, the D'Alembert solution just keeps working, oddly enough even for non-holomorphic $y_0$

Comment: no, I think I made a mistake there. The D'Alembert solution keeps working for holomorphic $y_0$.